# Is my thinking correct for partial derivatives and tensors?

Tags: differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, coordinate-systems, differentiation

So I was transforming the affine connection and I ended up with a term like this:
$$
\frac{\partial^2 x'^a}{\partial x'^b \partial x^p}
$$

where $x$ and $x'$ are two different coordinate systems

Luckily there were two of these and they cancelled, however, does this term equal 0?

Part of me thinks so as $\frac{\partial x'^a}{\partial x'^b}=\delta ^a_b$ however for a later question doing this didn't work.

Also, do partial derivatives still commute if we differentiate with respect to different coordinate systems?

Comment: If they cancelled, you'd better hope they don't equal zero.

Comment: @Paul I assume he meant a cancellation in the context of a sum of identical terms with opposite sign.